# Django output all annotations from a queryset on a single row

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

A company is assigned many tasks per month. Each task can have three options pending, in progress and completed. For example: based on my query for period 01/2021 i get the correct result however i am unable to list them properly on the template where each company should appears just once in a row along with the count for each option.

**Models.py**

```
class Company(models.Model):
    company = models.CharField(max_length=40)

class Period(models.Model):
    period = models.CharField(max_length=7)

class Status(models.Model):
    option = models.CharField(max_length=40)

class Task(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    period = models.ForeignKey(Period, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
```

**Views.py**

```
if request.method == 'POST':
            if form.is_valid():
                periods = Period.objects.get(period=form.cleaned_data['period'])
                status = Task.objects.filter(period=periods).values('period', 'company__compnay', 'status__option', 'status').annotate(count_pending=Count('status', filter=Q(status=1))).annotate(count_inprogress=Count('status', filter=Q(status=2))).annotate(count_completed=Count('status', filter=Q(status=3))))
            args = {'form': form, 'periods': periods, 'status': status}
```

**Template**

```
{% if status %}
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Company</th>
                        <th scope="col">Tasks Pending</th>
                        <th scope="col">Tasks In Progress</th>
                        <th scope="col">Tasks Completed</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {% for stat in status %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{stat.company__company}}</td>
                            <td>{{stat.count_pending}}</td>
                            <td>{{stat.count_inprogress}}</td>
                            <td>{{stat.count_completed}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        {% endif %}
```

**Results**

```
Company       Tasks Pending         Tasks In Progress       Completed
Apple         0                     0                       1
Apple         0                     1                       0
Apple         2                     0                       0
Microsoft     0                     0                       2
Microsoft     0                     5                       0
Microsoft     5                     0                       2
```

**Expected Result**

```
Company     Pending Tasks   In Progress Tasks   Completed Tasks
Apple       2               1                   1
Microsoft   5               5                   2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This must be what you want:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Case, When

Task.objects.filter(period=periods).values(
    "company__company").annotate(
        total_tasks=Count("company"),
        count_pending=Count(Case(When(status=1, then=1))),
        count_inprogress=Count(Case(When(status=2, then=1))),
        count_completed=Count(Case(When(status=3, then=1))),
    ).order_by("company")
```

Comment: I am getting one row for each company however its not counting. All the columns show 0

Comment: @RoniX, use `status=1` instead `status__option`.